# Prevent the touchpad from performing clicks while typing

Tags: touchpad

When I'm typing, accidental clicks from my touchpad are performed, like switching the line where the cursor is, or the whole window. I want to prevent this.

My current test to verify if a solution satisfies my needs is to open a terminal and press only one key over and over again and at the same time pressing a click on the touchpad. If the line/ window changes the test failed.

Solutions I tried:

- syndaemon
- Touchpad-indicator

I currently run Ubuntu 16.04, but had the same issue on nearly all my operating systems. I also checked `xinput list`, and only one touchpad is recognized. My touchpad manager is SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad.

Comment: Yes, its a duplicate. thanks for pointing it out. Should I delete the Question ?

Comment: You may, if you want. If you don't it may be put on hold as duplicate, and slowly fade away from view :)